# How do I get a new ArgoCD installation to run on its own?

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I am trying to set up ArgoCD, and am unclear on some of its directions. I am a Kubernetes beginner and am experimenting to learn. I've set up my own Kubernetes master and two workers on VMs, and so far so good. (VMs and real k8s because I want to dig in...) Next I've installed ArgoCD and got it to run, according to https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/getting_started/.

Following the instructions led me to run ArgoCD with Port Forwarding. This is a process running on a terminal on the kubernetes master. And it works for me, great.

I would expect people normally want ArgoCD to run without a foreground process, but the ArgoCD instructions and all the various instructables around left me hanging.

What's the next step to have ArgoCD run on its own?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that what you're actually seeing is ArgoCD running as a "foreground process." The API server is running in a pod. I think what you're seeing in the foreground is `kubectl` forwarding a port so you can access the ArgoCD API/UI.

In order to avoid running the `kubectl` port-forward (in the foreground or anywhere else), you need to set up a more "permanent/proper" way of accessing the API.

The [ArgoCD instructions](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/getting_started/#3-access-the-argo-cd-api-server) are a bit brief about how to set up access. But you should try either the LoadBalancer or Ingress approach. It'll probably take a little external research about what those *are* in the Kubernetes world to understand which is best and how to use it.

For a private cluster, one option is to set up [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) on the cluster, in particular see [installation](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/) then [configuration](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/). Configure the LB with a Layer2 configuration using a private IP range. Then, update ArgoCD with the command provided in the [ArgoCD instructions](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/getting_started/#3-access-the-argo-cd-api-server) for a load balancer. Once all set up, find the Load Balancer assigned IP with `kubectl get service -n argocd` and the external IP's port 80 should route to an ArgoCD pod IP port 8080.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't mean to imply ArgoCD was "the" foreground process, but "a" foreground process was necessary. Now resolved this way: I installed https://metallb.universe.tf/ to give this VM cluster a LB, set it up for a private LAN address range, and then turned on Load Balancer using the step from ArgoCD docs, and Argo UI works from port 80 on the LB assigned address. The address is found on kubectl get service -n argocd. Easier than I thought.

Comment: @jws Sweet! If you wanna edit my answer to include a walkthrough or add an answer of your own, that would be great. You're right, the docs are pretty light.